# Consuming web service using C#- Unable to catch exception in AX(2009)

Tags: try-catch, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I have created a AIF- document service in AX 2009. I am doing a picking list registration update in AX. I have my code in try and catch in AX.

MY ISSUE:

when I test the service in AX through a test job, I can able to catch the exception in the catch code. But, when I consume the service through C#, I can't able to catch the exception. In other words, the code is not coming to the catch part.

I don't know why I can't catch exception when I am consuming the service.

Any suggestions would be helpful..

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you take a look at [Debugging AIF Web Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2011/01/19/debugging-aif-web-services/)? Are you sure that the service is executed when you call it from C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't catch exception inside AIF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830973/cant-catch-exception-inside-aif-service)

Comment: @FH-Inway Thanks for the reply. I found it helpful.